# Worklight 6.1 Server not running in Windows 2012

Tags: worklight-server, worklight-runtime

Good day to everyone!

We have this old worklight 6.1 server (left behind) which is running in Windows 2003 server. We need to move this server to Windows 2012 but having issue when starting the app server. Is Worklight supported with Windows Server 2012? If not, what's the workaround? Thank you in advance.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: I need answer for following question .Which app server you are using and what is the version of app server?

Comment: We are using Apache Tomcat 7.0.